# Can xlwt create a hyperlink in a cell with variables for both the title and link?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

For instance,

How would the following line be changed such that "test" is variable T and "http://google.com" is variable L?

```
ws.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula('"test " & HYPERLINK("http://google.com")'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
T = 'test'
L = 'http://google.com'
formula = '"{} " & HYPERLINK("{}")'.format(T, L)
ws.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula(formula))
```

This uses [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the values of variables `T` and `L` in to the string `formula`. Following the above assignments `formula` will contain:

```
"test " & HYPERLINK("http://google.com")
```

It's also possible to do it without using the temporary variable:

```
ws.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula('"{} " & HYPERLINK("{}")'.format(T, L)))
```

**Update**

The code above answers the question as it was stated, however, the OP actually requires that "test" be displayed as the link and the URL be the target, so:

```
T = 'test'
L = 'http://google.com'
formula = 'HYPERLINK("{}", "{}")'.format(L, T)
ws.write(0, 0, xlwt.Formula(formula))

>>> formula
'HYPERLINK("http://google.com", "test")'
```

Comment: This is getting somewhere, but I expected the link to be invisible. This makes the cell contain both the title and the link.

Comment: @Phillip: in that case you need to use the display name in the `HYPERLINK()` function properly, i.e. `HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])`. I've updated the answer to reflect that.